# Software compass sensor

Tags: sensors, compass-geolocation, emulation

Is there a way to develop a compass sensor emulator (based on GPS travel direction), so for devices that has no compass sensor (but has GPS) can emulate the hardware sensor? This way apps that want to use the compass can still work fairly accurately.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Sure, there is a way. Next question.

Comment: Thanks Matt for the answer. Are there any android apps you know of ? or can someone build one? I'm sure there are many who would be interested in using such app. I searched and searched but couldn't find any.